# How to set environment variable in vimrc?

Tags: vim, neovim

My home and end key is not working in neovim. I am connecting via Mtputty.
I found that setting terminal in environment variable made it as work.

```
export TERM=putty-256color
```

But whenever i close the session , next time i had to set.
So i tried to add it in .vimrc.
I am setting TERM environment path via vimrc like below.

```
if has('nvim')
  let $TERM = 'putty-256color'
endif
```

But it is not working .

How to set environment variable in vimrc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:let $VARNAME = expression`  is the way to proceed -- Note: only expressions that evaluate as integers or strings will be valid: [`:h expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expression).

It's quite likely that nvim has already processed `$TERM` value. Changing it while nvim is already running is too late. Updated environment variables will mostly be used by subprocesses and plugins that read them at the last moment.

IMO, you'd better define an alias on `nvim` that'll mask the default program, and set the environment variable before running `\nvim`, e.g.:

```sh
# bash function
nvim() {
    export TERM=putty-256color 
    \nvim "$@"
}
```

Comment: I had to put double quotes in value ( `:let $VARNAME = "value"`)

Comment: @PrakashP By value I meant expression, sorry. Numbers could be directly assigned. Strings need to be quoted (with either single or double quotes... see another Q/A regarding the difference between the two)

Comment: Appreciate for the quick reply. I upvoted your answer. Commented on your answer so that it may be helpful to the readers of your answers.